# Fail to decode a video with ffmpeg, but it can be played by video player

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i have a video witch can be played by players. But, I failed to decode it using ffmpeg 3.4.
Actually， it failed on the ffmpeg libs compiled by myself, but success on a common ffmpeg-3.4 lib of my company.

My compilation seems success, as i can use it to decode most of my videos.

Whats wrong with my lib? If i should enable some special options when compiling?
Anything special on this video?

error message:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x31b7120] STSC entry 1 is invalid (first=12 count=0 id=1)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x31b7120] stream 0, contradictionary STSC and STCO
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x31b7120] error reading header
```

video info dumped when i use libs of my company

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'aaa':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2019-08-06T16:42:23.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:10.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2815 kb/s, 25.66 fps, 25.64 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-08-06T16:42:24.000000Z
      handler_name    :
      encoder         : VC Coding
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in May of 2018. Update your version of ffmpeg.

Comment: I have tried 4.1.4 and 3.4.7 version and get the same result.

Comment: It's now 2021 and this issues still occurs.